# How to send mutipart/mixed;boudary=batch using rest assured in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest-assured

I have searched to send the data as a batch to rest end points. But didn't got a correct solution. Could you please help me on this.

PFB the sample body of the data.

```
--batch
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset


--changeset
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


POST CorporateAccountCollection HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-ID: 2
Content-Length: 10000


{
    "Name":"Testing Batch Operation MB", 
    "RoleCode":"XXXXX", 
    "CountryCode":"US", 
    "CorporateAccountIdentification" : [
        {
            "IDTypeCode":"XXXXXX",
            "IDNumber":"9999999999"
        }
    ]
}


--changeset--
--batch--
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534953/rest-assured-audio-file-upload-with-multipart-mixed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124388/how-to-send-a-multipart-request-with-restassured

Comment: Thanks. Its about to send a file as body .Here i need to send the whole data i mentioned in the question as body